# How do I change my Minecraft username using the Mojang API?

Tags: python, api, minecraft

Is it possible to change my Minecraft username with python using the mojang API? I’ve looked everywhere and can’t find anywhere that tells me how to do it, besides [this documentation](https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Change_Name) which I can’t understand. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Whenever you are using an API, chances are someone on GitHub has done so before you. Plenty of examples are here: https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.minecraftservices.com%2Fminecraft%2Fprofile%2Fname%2F&type=Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
import requests

name = "YOUR_NEW_USERNAME"
url = f"https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/{name}"
token = "YOUR_TOKEN"
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
response = requests.put(url,headers=headers)
```

I do not play Minecraft anymore, but the documentation states that you need to send a PUT request to `https://api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/<name>`, where `<name>` is your new username.

You can then check the response via `response.json()`.